# What happens if an independent candidate in the UK gets two seats worth of votes in EU elections?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, european-union, european-parliament

During the UK election for the European parliament, what happens if an independent candidate gets enough votes for two seats? Do they nominate someone to get the seat? Do the votes get shared out amongst the other candidates? Does the MEP get to vote twice in all votes? Or is the seat left empty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great Britain uses a system called d'Hondt's method.  This allocates seats to parties one at a time, as follows:

- For each list (party or independent candidate), a priority is calculated: *P = V/(S+1)*, where *P* is the priority to be calculated, *V* is the number of votes cast for this list, and *S* is the number of seats won by this list so far.
- The list that has the highest calculated priority will get the next seat.
- This is repeated until all seats have been allocated

If a list is exhausted (for example, an independent candidate is elected), then that list's priority is no longer calculated, and the excess votes for that list are effectively wasted.

For the sake of a hypothetical example, let's take a five-seat constituency which votes as follows:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Seat | LAB | IND | CON | LD  | Awarded to | Notes                                             |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|   1  | 40% | 30% | 20% | 10% | LAB        |                                                   |
|   2  | 20% | 30% | 20% | 10% | IND        | IND list now exhausted, so no priority calculated |
|   3  | 20% | N/A | 20% | 10% | LAB        |                                                   |
|   4  | 13% | N/A | 20% | 10% | CON        |                                                   |
|   5  | 13% | N/A | 10% | 10% | LAB        | Would be IND if this list had a second candidate  |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Well it seems a little unfair that the indepdendent only gets one seat. But thems the rules I guess.

Comment: Well, the Independent is only one person, and one person cannot occupy multiple seats. If the said independent expects such a high result, (s)he would be wise to gather some mates and register a party so they can get multiple seats.

Comment: Note that this only applies to England, Scotland and Wales. Northern Ireland uses a different voting scheme.

Comment: @Abigail I think the independent should get two votes if he wins two seets. That would reflect the propotional will of the people.

Comment: @Abigail Why not? What difference does it make if you have 10 people following the party line or one person voting 10 times? If the public don't like it they can vote for someone else.

Comment: @zooby: That's really a separate question (which you should ask if you want a full answer), but basically, that's not how representative democracy works. Parties can tell their MEPs how to vote, but the MEPs are ultimately independent actors who have to decide for themselves when and whether to listen.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Good spot. Tweaked my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Abigail If the members of the party defect then they aren't doing what they were voted in for. So why is that better? An independent could also be uncertain and maybe vote two ways on an issue. I can't see any reason why an independent with 10 votes is any less democratic than a party of 10 people, if that is who the public voted for. It would be less democratic if the independent got 90% of the public vote but votes were redistributed to other parties.

Comment: BTW that's why proportional representation doesn't really work that well. At least first past the post is more like a simulation of civil war in which only one faction wins.